# public property of gridview column in usercontrol to get value from master form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, devexpress

How can I make a public property of specific gridview column that beings in usercontrol to get value from master form,
the type of this column is 'Integer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is making the datagrid public.

The other way is making a property on the usercontrol:

```
Public Property DataGridProp() As String
    Get
        Return DataGridView1.Property
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        DataGridView1.Property = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I want the other way that beings on usercontrol

Comment: If you put the code on the usercontrol, you will be able to access the property perfectly

Comment: If I put this code, I'm facing this error "Property is not member of GridView", I'm using DevExpress Tools

Comment: Well, you need to change `DataGridView1.Property` to `DataGridView1.ThePropertyYouWantToHaveAccessTo`. It will be `´DataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName")` probably

Comment: ok, On 'get' section no problem, but on 'set' section facing this error 'Property item is read only'

Comment: What do you want the column for? Are you going to replace it? or just acces it? The thing is you will not need the set unles you want to `grid.columns("col")= new datagridcolumn` or something similar. As long as you use the column methods you will not neet the set (so you can delete the set line)